# Find the conditioning of the function

Tags: functions, polynomials, numerical-methods, condition-number

Evaluate the function $f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$. Check for what values of $x$ is $f(x)$ ill conditioned.

I had this question in a test and using the formula of the condition, $C(x)=|\frac{x  f'(x)}{f(x)}|$, I came to the conclusion that the function is well conditioned for all $x$ but the right answer is that the function is well conditioned for any value other than $x=0$, I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

My solution:

$f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$

$f'(x)=1-\frac{1}{x^2}$

$C(x)=|\frac{x  f'(x)}{f(x)}|$ where $C(x)$.

$C(x)= |\frac{x(1-\frac{1}{x^2})}{x+\frac{1}{x}}| = |\frac{x-\frac{1}{x}}{x+\frac{1}{x}}|= |\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}|$

$C(x)= |\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}|$

And $C(0)=1$ which is a small value so why is $f(x)$ ill conditioned at $x=0$?

Comment: How are you defining "ill-condifioned"?

Comment: @lulu According to what I learned in class, it is when the value of C(x) is very large for a particular value of x, the function is ill conditioned for that value of x.

Comment: But $C(0)$ isn't even defined, as neither $f(0)$ nor $f'(0)$ is defined.  And "very large" isn't terribly precise.  What happens if my notion of very large is different from yours?

Comment: @lulu I had that doubt too, but this is the solution to these types of questions given by professor but I think it means when the condition number $C(x)->\infty $

Comment: I expect it includes points for which $C(x)$ is undefined.

Comment: And, again, $C(x)$ is undefined at $x=0$.

Comment: @lulu Could you explain how? it seems to me that $C(0) =1$

Comment: Neither $f(0)$ nor $f'(0)$ is defined.  The fact that you can analytically continue over that point is not relevant.

Comment: Conditioning is of interest for numerical approximation.  Any attempt to numerically compute $f(0)$ or $f'(0)$ will end in disaster.

Comment: @lulu ohh i see, so $f(0)$ and $f'(0)$ also have to be well defined. In that case, shouldn't the solution that $f(x)$ is ill conditioned for $x\approx 0$ ? According to the answer, it says that $f(x)$ is well conditioned for any value of $x!=0$

Comment: As  I mentioned, I don't understand what definition you are using.  But $C(x)<1$ for all $x\neq 0$ and I think that that range is small by anyone's definition.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the method that was used was correct but the function is well conditioned for all values of $x \neq 0$ and here is the calculation:

$f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$

$f'(x)=1-\frac{1}{x^2}$

$C(x)=|\frac{x  f'(x)}{f(x)}|$ where $C(x)$.

$C(x)= |\frac{x(1-\frac{1}{x^2})}{x+\frac{1}{x}}| = |\frac{x-\frac{1}{x}}{x+\frac{1}{x}}|$

$C(x)= |\frac{x(1-\frac{1}{x^2})}{x(1+\frac{1}{x^2})}|$  (We cannot cancel out the zeros since $\frac{0}{0}$ is undefined)

for $x=0, C(x)$ is undefined and is well conditioned for all $x ∈R$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that you have been given is not correct. You have correctly computed the *relative* condition number $C$ for the function $f$ at every point where $f$ is defined and $$\forall x \not = 0 \: : \: C(x) = \frac{|x^2-1|}{x^2+1}.$$ You have that $$C(x) \leq 1$$ so $f$ is well-conditioned in the relative sense for all $x \not = 0$. The *absolute* condition number of a (differentiable) function $f$ is $$K(x) = |f'(x)|.$$ Your function is ill-conditioned in the absolute sense near $x = 0$ because $$f'(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{x^2} \rightarrow -\infty, \quad x \rightarrow 0, \quad x \not = 0.$$

Many textbooks focus on relative condition numbers and omit absolute condition numbers. Relative condition numbers are natural when using floating point numbers because real numbers can be represented with a small relative error. Absolute condition numbers should not be neglected because absolute errors tend to be important in real applications. Example: It does not matter if an artillery shell travels 5 km or 50 km. The only thing that matters is the absolute distance from the target to the point of impact. Is this distance less than the kill radius of the exploding shell or not?

Comment: Actually, the correct answer is that the function is well conditioned for all values other than x=0 and we can do this using condition number since at x=0, C(x) is undefined.